# Set SPUser command in powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

Can someone please confirm if this powershell command for Sharepoint 2010 does sends email when adding users to SP groups. I cannot test it out right now so just confirming whether it does which if is the case how can I not make it send email to the user when being added to the group.

Comparing this in the UI when you add user to the group there is a default check box for sending email to users.

```
Set-SPUser -Identity 'Contoso\jdow' -Web http://test -AddPermissionLevel "Contributor"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code you supplied doesn't add a user to a SharePoint group.  It gives the user contributor access to a site.  By default, this will not send an email. You would have to write your powershell Script to do send the email.

To add a user to a group, you would do this

```
Set-SPUser -Identity 'Contoso\jdow' -Web http://test -Group 'groupname'
```